# why is animate( opacity:1 ) making my font-weight change?

Tags: jquery-animate

I have a slider where i make the content fade in and out starting with opacity:0; and then it runs this function. When this happens my text's font-weight shows up normal for the first 499 milliseconds then it jolts to bold at the end of the animation. Any clue as to why it does that and how to fix it?

```
s2.animate({
    opacity:1
    },500)
```